# Fix button on screen

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am using a ScrollView and a RelativeLayout under it. I've a button at the bottom of the screen. **I want the button to move with the screen while scrolling.** Button should be present at the bottom right corner of the screen.

I've tried using FrameLayout as stated in one of the answers related to this issue but I want my button to be there at the bottom right corner of the screen.
As of now button is present at the bottom of the whole screen which means you will have to scroll down a bit to see it.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.android.app1.SecondScreen">

    <TextView
        android:text="Check all the Symptoms which apply - "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <CheckBox1>
    <CheckBox2>
    <CheckBox3>
    <CheckBox4>
    <CheckBox5>
    <CheckBox6>
    <CheckBox7>
    <CheckBox8>
    <CheckBox9>
    <CheckBox10>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:text="submit"
            android:id="@+id/submitbutton"
            android:layout_below="@id/Lastcheckbox"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

**You will need a floating action button for that:**

```
<RelativeLayout
 ...
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/myFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_sign"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        ... />
```

...

**In your app level gradle**

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

To get the whole working project

> Update Android Studio to 1.5
>
> Create a new project wit Blank Activity, it automatically generates for you!

Comment: I've downloaded the latest update but how to do the update now ?

Comment: If your android studio is not 1.4+ , then go to help-> check for updates. If you have 1.4+ version...then you are all set to get the fab generated by android studio, just creating a new blank project will do the stuff for you

Comment: I've android 1.2. After clicking help->check for updates is it asking to download the update . I've already downloaded the update. How should I proceed further ?

Comment: let it download and install...it restarts itself...!

Answer (score 1):

Use `FloatingActionBar` instead of normal button it always at bottom right of the screen, Use Design Support library.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Comment: How to use appcompat v7 library ?

Comment: take a loot at this link http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: if you're having it just add the library to your dependencies

Comment: @sathishkumar `FloatingActionButton` is in `support:design` library not in v7. Please update your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your scrollview with button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/submitbutton">
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      tools:context="com.example.android.app1.SecondScreen">

    <TextView
        android:text="Check all the Symptoms which apply - "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <CheckBox1/>
    <CheckBox2/>
    <CheckBox3/>
    <CheckBox4/>
    <CheckBox5/>
    <CheckBox6/>
    <CheckBox7/>
    <CheckBox8/>
    <CheckBox9/>
    <CheckBox10/>


  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
  <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="25sp"
      android:text="submit"
      android:id="@+id/submitbutton"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `FloatingActionButton` like the others stated.
OR
you could place the `ScrollView` in a `LinearLayout` and place the button after the `ScrollView`, like so:

```
<LinearLayout ....>
   <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width=".."
    android:layout_height="0" 
    android:layout_weight="1">
       <RelativeLayout>
       .
       .
       .
       </RelativeLayout>
   </ScrollView>
   <Button android:layout_gravity = "right" ..... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Don't you think that using LinearLayout will eliminate the option to place the button on the right side of the screen ?

Comment: you can always do <Button android:layout_gravity="right"> :D